# how do I change the colour of google drive embeded progress bar instead of red i would like to have white bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, google-drive-api

on YouTube embedded video this is how you do it `<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QH2-TGUlwu4?color=white" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

is there way i can do it on google drive embedder video

Comment: Read your question and ask your self how anyone can help you.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

#### No, there is no way known

This comes from Google's side and looking at the documentation, there seems to be no way.

From the inspector it seems that the element is:

[image]

However, it is not possible to change the CSS of an item in an iframe if it doesn't come from the same origin. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

So this:

```html
<div style=".ytp-swatch-background-color{background-color:white;}">
    <iframe
        src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/[YOUR VIDEO ID]/preview"
        width="640"
        height="480"
    >
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Is not possible

Adding:

`?color=white`

To the end of the drive embed does nothing either.

Google controls how to display their embeds, if they didn't decide to add the functionality to Drive embeds, then there will almost certainly not be a way.

#### Workaround

So if you really need this, then maybe best to upload the video to YouTube and make it unpublished so only people with link can see it.